# Ho do i redirect to login page if error occured while renewing aad token?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, azure-active-directory

i'm using react-adal to authenticate react-typescript app . Everything works fine after login but if i keep logged in and if tried to access site after let's say one hour i'm getting

> AADSTS50058: A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in.

Is there any way to redirect user to login page if token renewal is failed or renew token before getting expired. If you have any other solution please suggest.

Comment: The token is renewed when near expiration in `acquireTokenSilent` method. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535366/acquiring-new-access-token-using-refresh-token-adal-js?answertab=votes#tab-top). Please let me know if it's helpful.

Comment: In case renewal failed or got error while acquiring token then i wanted to redirect user to login page.